# Prevent Forever from starting duplicate processes

Tags: python, node.js, forever

I'm using a Python script to execute multiple shell commands (eg: `forever start -c python <filename>.py`) to start several Python scripts under [Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever).

Sometimes I will forget to stop some of the processes through forever and run the Python script again, resulting in duplicate processes running.

In Forever, is it possible to prevent starting a duplicate process if one is already running?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer. How would Forever decide if a process is a duplicate?

I did have a similar requirement, and found two ways to handle. One is just to run forever stop  first so be sure there is no current running process

Or a slightly more complex way is to use "forever list --plain" and then search the output of that for the  to see if it is running, and then you can stop it only if it is running